# Grab image position using var id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a number of images dynamically displayed on a page with dynamic IDs.

I want to grab the position of an image when clicked on so I can adjust the position of another element.

My code below does not seem to work:

```
    var selImg = $(this).attr('id');

    var pos = $(selImg).position();
    alert(pos.top);
```

I get a JS error saying "pos" is undefined.

Comment: I believe you meant `var pos = $("#" + selImg).position();`

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `selImg` to the `id` of `$(this)`.

You need to set `selImg` to `$(this)` to appropriately select the element.  Right now you're trying to call `position` on a string.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling it anonymously,

```
var pos = $(this).position()
alert(pos.top);
```

or call it with the id

```
var pos = $('#id').position()
alert(pos.top);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var position = getPosition(this);
});

//Found this function online
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```